# Multiple entity types using the same endpoint/controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing, ravendb

I'm using RavenDB in my application and by default the id to a document looks something like this:

```
homes/1
```

where `homes` is the collection type name of the class `Home`. If I create a new class called `Blog` I will end up with an id like:

```
blogs/1
```

Now, both `Home` and `Blog` are pages in my CMS and I would like both `homes/1` and `blogs/1` to use the `PageController`. So, is it possible to do this using a constraint or something like that because it's important that only types that inherits a specific class are handled by the `PageController` endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

You have two different options.

If it is a `PagesController`, and the user is performing objects like creating and editing pages, then there probably shouldn't be two separate entity types for `Home` and `Blog`.  There should simply be a `Page` class.  It can have a `PageType` property to distinguish between them, but they probably don't need to be separate objects.  If you take this approach, you will have documents in RavenDB with keys like `pages/1`.

If there are *distinctly* different fields, then perhaps you *do* have a `Home` and `Blog` class, but they should both inherit from a `Page` class and any properties in common should go there.  If you take this approach, you will still get documents in RavenDB with keys like `homes/1` and `blogs/1`.  You might want to look at [this page](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/client-api/querying/polymorphism) on Polymorphism in RavenDB.  With this approach, you might still want a `PagesController`, or you might want separate `HomePagesController` and `BlogPagesController` depending on your needs.

Comment: The fields on the entity types my differ a lot. I agree with you and I think the best solution is to create a `Controller` for each `Type` and that would work in a normal scenario where I create all classes. In my case I create the `Page` class and a multi map index that indexes all types inheriting `Page`. Another developer, using my CMS to create a site creates the `Home` and `Blog` classes. In the UI of my CMS the content editor should be able to edit and save all `Home`s, `Blog`s etc. So that's why I *think* I need to have a single `PageController` for all Pages.

Comment: So, are you encountering a specific problem that doesn't work with your current approach?

Comment: It works if I use the identity strategy with the dash instead of forward slash because then I end up with urls like page/homes-1 and that works great. One of the reasons I ask this question is because I'm trying to implement document drafts like this homes/1/draft but I guess homes-1-draft would work just nice to even though it doesn't look that nice. But you understand if you extend my `Page` class and add more fields to it the I will experience problems when saving it because there are no `Controller` handling the `Type` you created?